# ExtJs removing and adding listeners. Caching issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an object wich caches windows with all their internal structure (form, other ui elements). So when a user opens a window which has already been cached, it does create it from scratch, but takes if from cache and just show it like this:

```
winCache[id_group].show();
```

So, for each `id_group`, there is a `window` which may be cached in `winCache`. The problem is that I want to reset a `form`, which is inside the `window`, and populate it with new data from database. I try to do it like this:

```
if(winCache[id_group]){
    winCache[id_group].removeListener('show');
    winCache[id_group].addListener('show', function () {
      populate_form(this, id_field); // <-- this method retreives data from database 
   // and sets the form  
    });
    winCache[id_group].show();  
}
else { // window was not cached and has to be created from scratch
  var win = ...
  win.show();
  // ... some BIG procedure
  winCache[id_group] = win; // next time it will be taken from cache
}
```

But the problem is, for some insane reason, `ExtJS` duplicates `show` listeners infinitely. So, for example, if I open `winCache[10]` seven times for the same `id_group` = `10`, but for different `id_field`s (id_field = 1, id_field = 2, ..., id_field = 7), then `show` listener will be triggered seven times - for each id_field. And that is incredible stupidity. So, my question is why `ExtJS` duplicates listeners? And why doesn't `removeListener` work???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`removeListener`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.EventManager-method-removeListener) expects a function reference as the second argument.

If this code you've added is executed each time the window should be displayed may be using `single: true` on the `addListener` will solve your issue (so you don't need to `removeListener`), try:

```
winCache[id_group].addListener('show', function () {

}, null, { single: true });
```

If that's not the case, you'll need to save a reference to the `show` function you'r passing to `addListener` so you'll be able to pass it to `removeListener`, or may be use `destroyable`, like:

```
winCache[id_group].destroyShowEvent && winCache[id_group].destroyShowEvent.destry();
winCache[id_group].destroyShowEvent = winCache[id_group].addListener('show', function () {

}, null, { destroyable: true });
```